# How can I save media files without making a second network request?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, download

Let's say that I open a the Developer Console in a standard web browser like Chrome or Firefox and go to example.com.

After the page finishes loading, I take a look through the Network tab and find an audio file that I want to download (example.mp3).

Unfortunately, I then discover that my Internet connection has gone down and won't be back up for a while.

How can I download the MP3 file that the browser has already loaded? If I try to open it in a new tab, the browser will tell me that my connection is down. But I don't want to download the file again, I just want to save the copy that's already been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for a forensic tools.

My approach would be to try and download the data that is in the cache of your browser. Assuming you are using google chrome, you could for instance use [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html), which helps read it and sort it for convenient manipulation.